# C++ compile time polymorphism example

Tags: c++, object-oriented, polymorphism, variant-type

I found an example using std::variant to provide compile time polymorphism as a possible optimisation to runtime polymorphism in 'Software Architecture Using C++', https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Software-Architecture-with-Cpp, in the Dependency Inversion Principle chapter.

I had a C++ code example using runtime polymorphism, ie using virtual functions and an interface class.  And I wanted to experiment to see how how I could achieve compile time polymorphism using this code.  The runtime polymorphism code had a factory that did this to decide which object to return to the calling code:

```
#include "ScreenGrabberFactory.hpp"

#include "WindowsScreenGrabber.hpp"
#include "LinuxScreenGrabber.hpp"

std::unique_ptr<IScreenGrabber> makeScreenGrabber() {
#ifdef _WIN32
    return std::make_unique<WindowsScreenGrabber>();
#elif __linux__
    return std::make_shared<LinuxScreenGrabber>();
#else
    #error Your platform is not currently supported by ScreenGrabber
#endif
}
```

So the challenge was how to convert the code.

The files that might invite criticism are the Linux and Windows implementation files with the #ifdef's.  But maybe it is ok.  Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Here is my implementation.

main.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

#include "ScreenGrabberFactory.hpp"

int main() {
    GrabberType grabber = makeScreenGrabber();
    std::cout << "grabber index " << grabber.index() << std::endl;  // just to check correct index printed out

    std::visit([](auto& grab) { 
        grab.Capture();
        std::string supported = grab.GetSupportedMimeTypes();
        if (supported.find("image/bmp") != std::string::npos) {
            std::string basename{ "captured" };
            grab.Save(basename, "image/bmp");
        }
    }, grabber);
}
```

factory header - ScreenGrabberFactory.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include "LinuxScreenGrabber.hpp"
#include "WindowsScreenGrabber.hpp"

#include <variant>

using GrabberType = std::variant<LinuxScreenGrabber, WindowsScreenGrabber>;

GrabberType makeScreenGrabber();
```

factory implementation, ScreenGrabberFactory.cpp:

```
#include "ScreenGrabberFactory.hpp"

GrabberType makeScreenGrabber() {
#ifdef _WIN32
    return WindowsScreenGrabber{};
#elif __linux__
    return LinuxScreenGrabber{};
#else
#error Your platform is not currently supported by ScreenGrabber
#endif
}
```

Linux impl hdr, LinuxScreenGrabber.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class LinuxScreenGrabber {
public:
    bool Capture();
    bool Save(const std::string& basename, const std::string& imageMimeType);
    std::string GetSupportedMimeTypes() const;
};
```

Linux impl, LinuxScreenGrabber.cpp:

```
#include "LinuxScreenGrabber.hpp"

#include <iostream>

bool LinuxScreenGrabber::Capture() {
#ifdef __linux__
    // Linux implementation
    std::cout << "Linux capture\n";
#endif // __linux__
    return true;
}

bool LinuxScreenGrabber::Save(const std::string& basename, const std::string& imageMimeType) {
#ifdef __linux__
    // Linux implementation
    std::cout << "Linux save\n";
#endif // __linux__
    return true;
}

std::string LinuxScreenGrabber::GetSupportedMimeTypes() const {
    return "image/bmp";
}
```

Windows impl hdr, WindowsScreenGrabber.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class WindowsScreenGrabber {
public:
    bool Capture();
    bool Save(const std::string& basename, const std::string& imageMimeType);
    std::string GetSupportedMimeTypes() const;
};
```

Windows impl, WindowsScreenGrabber.cpp:

```
#include "WindowsScreenGrabber.hpp"

#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>

bool WindowsScreenGrabber::Capture() {
#ifdef _WIN32
     // Windows implementation
    std::cout << "Windows capture\n";
#endif // _WIN32
    return true;
}

bool WindowsScreenGrabber::Save(const std::string& basename, const std::string& imageMimeType) {
#ifdef _WIN32
    // Windows implementation
    std::cout << "Windows save\n";
#endif // _WIN32
    return true;
}

std::string WindowsScreenGrabber::GetSupportedMimeTypes() const {
    return "image/bmp";
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder that on Code Review we only review real working code from a project you have written. This question is too theoretical in nature. Example and demo code is off-topic on code review. The code needs to be providing a real solution to a programming problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not fulfill any need

Answer (score 2):

This is over-complicated.

We don't want `WindowsScreenGrabber` to exist at all on Linux, or `LinuxScreenGrabber` to exist on Windows. We instead want a single `ScreenGrabber` object that has a different implementation on each platform, but provides the same static interface, so we can use it the same way in the rest of the code, with no visible polymorphism at all.

In other-words, this is more a project setup / build-system issue.

(Note that there's no need to use a `class` here all. The "grabber" doesn't have any state. If we want to group related functions, the correct tool for that is a `namespace`, not a `class`).

For example, we could have a single header `ScreenGrab.hpp` that declares a function:

```
#pragma once

#include "Image.hpp" // platform independent Image class

Image grabScreen();
```

Then, ideally, we should have two different implementation files: `WindowsScreenGrab.cpp` and `LinuxScreenGrab.cpp`, that implement this function. We then include **only** the relevant file for the current build when compiling, by configuring our project correctly.

But, since this is remarkably fiddly to set up in various IDE's / build systems... if we *really* had to, we could instead implement a single file `ScreenGrab.cpp`:

```
#ifdef _WIN32

// windows includes...

Image grabScreen()
{
    // ... windows code
}

#elif __linux__

// linux includes...

Image grabScreen()
{
    // ... linux code
}

#else
    #error "Unsupported platform"
#endif
```

The image class could be identical between platforms, so we would only need a single image class, and a single cross-platform save function. (If this is impractical, due to image format differences (or something), we might want to implement a `grabScreenToFile(filename)` function instead to isolate the complexity.)

In any case, we want to minimize the number of `#ifdef`s to avoid making the code harder to follow.